How to send transaction using Safe Wallet with wagmi connector?
I am trying to develop a Safe Global dApp using viem and wagmi's Safe connector (https://wagmi.sh/react/api/connectors/safe).
When I tried to send a transaction (call some contract), it throws an error saying "unknown account".
I checked the transaction data and noticed that the from address is the Safe contract address. This might be the reason for the error, but not sure how can I fix this.
My config:
import { mainnet, sepolia } from "viem/chains";
import { safe } from "wagmi/connectors";

const connector = safe({
  allowedDomains: [/app.safe.global$/],
});

const config = createConfig({
  chains,
  connectors: [connector],
  transports: {
    [mainnet.id]: http(),
    [sepolia.id]: http(),
  },
});

Can't find any examples of sending transaction (write to contract in my case) through Safe's Wagmi connector even in official examples (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/main/examples/wagmi)

There is an example of a dummy contract write in the example app here. You can look at wagmi doc to know how to populate this example with the correct parameters (address, abi, and functionName).
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
